# Regex match remaining URL

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Ok, so tried messing with some patterns on a couple regex sites. Not sure why I can't get this.

How can I match all url params after account?

/account/**home/dashboard/**

/account/**random/place/place2/place3/**

I want to match any param after account ^

Comment: What code/regex are you stuck with?

Comment: Are you looking for [`\/(?!account).*`](https://regex101.com/r/aL5rO1/1)?

Comment: [`account/(.+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/yY6vC7/1)

Comment: \/(?!account).*  This works.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
path = "/account/home/dashboard/"
```

then

```
path.match(/\/account\/(.*)/)
```

will return

```
["/account/home/dashboard/", "home/dashboard/"]
```

So, what I think you want is to just call:

```
path.match(/\/account\/(.*)/)[1]
```

Comment: Yeah pretty much trying to match anything after account/ I messed with this   account/*\(*(.+) and seems to work, but not sure if it's correct.